# Dual boot Solaris and Linux

Tags: linux, solaris, grub2, dual-boot

I have a laptop running Oracle Solaris and Gentoo Linux.

First I installed Gentoo Linux. I used GPT partitioning scheme. In order to boot Gentoo Linux I have GRUB 2.

Then I installed Solaris 11.1. Now GRUB from Solaris overwrote the GRUB from Gentoo Linux and it didn't detect it and so currently I have only Solaris in the boot menu.

What I would like to do is to modify Solaris' GRUB configuration in order to do a dual boot by chainloading, since Solaris' GRUB does not support ext2 file system.

Unfortunately Solaris documentation about GRUB, which is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28983/glyem.html#scrolltoc), does not give an example about Linux - it's Windows only.

So I created `/rpool/boot/grub/custom.cfg`:

```
root@solaris:/rpool/boot/grub# cat custom.cfg
menuitem "Gentoo" {
    insmod gpt_part
    insmod chain
    set root=(hd0,ext2)
    chainload --force +1
}
```

and then rebooted.

When GRUB started, I saw only Solaris menu.

Do I have to run some additional commands on Gentoo Linux, in order for the GRUB configuration to take effect?

On Solaris, I didn't see anything like this in the docs.

What am I missing? At least the menuitem "Gentoo" should be visible in the GRUB.

GRUB configuration `/rpool/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
igor@solaris:~/Broadcom$ cat /rpool/boot/grub/grub.cfg
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d and settings from /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
}

if loadfont "/@/boot/grub/unicode.pf2" ; then
  set gfxmode="1024x768x32;1024x768x16;800x600x16;640x480x16;640x480x15;640x480x32"
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=($root)${prefix}/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_gpt
insmod zfs
set root=''
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e71191bc1127be5c
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e71191bc1127be5c
fi
insmod gfxmenu
loadfont ($root)//@/boot/grub/themes/solaris/liber18.pf2
loadfont ($root)//@/boot/grub/themes/solaris/univers16.pf2
loadfont ($root)//@/boot/grub/themes/solaris/univers20.pf2
insmod jpeg
insmod png
set theme=($root)//@/boot/grub/themes/solaris/theme.txt
set timeout=30
### END /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d/10_solaris ###
menuentry "Oracle Solaris 11.1" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod part_sunpc
    insmod part_gpt

    insmod zfs

    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e71191bc1127be5c
    zfs-bootfs /ROOT/solaris/@/ zfs_bootfs
    set kern=/platform/i86pc/kernel/amd64/unix
    echo -n "Loading ${root}/ROOT/solaris/@$kern: "
    $multiboot /ROOT/solaris/@/$kern $kern -B console=graphics -B $zfs_bootfs
    set gfxpayload="1024x768x32;1024x768x16;800x600x16;640x480x16;640x480x15;640x480x32"
    insmod gzio
    echo -n "Loading ${root}/ROOT/solaris/@/platform/i86pc/amd64/boot_archive: "
    $module /ROOT/solaris/@/platform/i86pc/amd64/boot_archive
}

if [ "$target" = "i386_pc" ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root_rpool e71191bc1127be5c
    if [ -s "($root_rpool)/@/boot/grub/menu.lst" ]; then
        submenu "Legacy GRUB Menu (from root pool rpool)" "($root_rpool)/@/boot/grub/menu.lst" {
            extract_legacy_entries_source "$2"
        }
    fi
fi

### END /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d/10_solaris ###

### BEGIN /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /usr/lib/grub2/bios/etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: This [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2379/fvbbb/index.html) talks about configuring grub for Solaris and Linux. It may be helpful if you have not already seen it.

Comment: Have you run `update-grub` before rebooting?

Comment: @Warwick, thank you for the link. No, I didn't see it. However, it looks like it talks about GRUB-legacy as 11.1 uses GRUB2.

Comment: @psimon, No I did not. However, global search reveal that there is no such command on Solaris.

Comment: @Warwick, Sorry hit Enter to early. ;-) The documentation link I referenced refer to the Solaris 11.1 and GRUB2 (both latest). It says all I need is to create that file as grub.cfg file references it. Please check it.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `/rpool/boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Comment: I wonder where $prefix gets defined? This file doesn't seem to source any other file, but refers to $prefix which doesn't seem to be defined. Any ideas?

Comment: @Warwick, Well it is automatically generated, so maybe it is stored somewhere inside GRUB2 or Solaris boot script?

Comment: I don't think that I can help any further unfortunately. I suspect though that if you post your question to the [Solaris x86 Yahoo group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/solarisx86/info) you will get a very quick diagnosis. They tend to have seen most Solaris x86 issues before.

Comment: Oh, and if they do give you a diagnosis, please post an answer here so anyone looking for an answer to you issue knows how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but instead of dealing with GRUB and dual-boot scenarios I've generally found it a lot easier to just use one base OS and then use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) whenever I wanted to use another OS. After these technologies have become so bloody effective I no longer see the need for dual-boot. Perhaps I missed something.  :-)

Comment: @peterh, I understand. However, as I'm a developer, I prefer to have a vanilla boot and not to use virtual environment. But more importantly how well VirtualBox can handle OpenGL?